# Error in joining two table using INNER JOIN with the replace keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to join 2 tables with INNER JOIN but the catch is I want to use REPLACE keyword as in another table there is an extra character in the text. I have written the query as :

```
SELECT
    keeper_details.*,
    keepers.*
FROM
    keeper_details
    INNER JOIN keepers ON keeper_details.cphh = keepers.CPHH SET keepers.CPHH = REPLACE(keepers.CPHH,"/","")
```

But I am getting an error saying as :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET keepers.CPHH = REPLACE(keepers.CPHH,"/","")

My common text is on `keeper table(CPHH) = "XXXXXXXX"` and on `keeper_details table(CPHH) = XX/XXX/XXXX`

I hope I am clear. I don't know where I am doing wrong! Any suggestions will be a great help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just have to fetch the details .

Comment: my common text in both the table is slightly different, which I have posted in the question. Please check

Comment: Why are you using SET?

Comment: SET belongs to UPDATE, not SELECT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
SELECT keeper_details.*
       , keepers.*
FROM keeper_details
INNER JOIN keepers
on keeper_details.cphh = REPLACE(keepers.CPHH,"/","");
```

When you are using the `on` word you are telling the query what to use as a "condition" when joining two tables. So when you remove the character '/' when joining all should be ok.

I also redommend to you to use single quotes when you using string values:

```
SELECT keeper_details.*
       , keepers.*
FROM keeper_details
INNER JOIN keepers
on keeper_details.CPHH = REPLACE(keepers.CPHH,'/','')
```

Comment: Thanks !! Yes I have wrote a terrible mistake!

Comment: Hi @Piyush, you are welcome. Learning is not a mistake ;)

Comment: Hi @Piyush, you can mark the answer as correct and vote it up :) Thanks :)